# What is keeping this rails project at an old rails version (or how can I find out what is keeping it at an old rails version)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gemfile

What is keeping this rails project at an old rails version (or how can I find out what is keeping it at an old rails version)?

I am looking at

https://github.com/mhartl/action_cable_chat_app

I cloned it, or forked and cloned it.

Granted, he has this in his Gemfile

```
gem 'rails',                   '5.0.1'
```

But I changed it to

```
gem 'rails'
```

and I did `bundle install` or `bundle update` or `bundle update rails`

and it went from the very old version(5.0.1), to `rails 5.0.7.2` which is still old.

If I `cd ..` then I see my global rails version, that's a recent version. `rails 5.2.3`

I can guess that maybe there is some gems in his Gemfile that require an early rails version and that is what is holding it back. But I can't verify that and if it were I don't know which.

I tried looking at Gemfile.lock and it says `rails (5.0.7.2)` So I tried `rm Gemfile.lock` then bundle update rails, and still, `rails 5.0.7.2`

Comment: Other gems are keeping it an older version, just comment out all the version numbers and run `bundle install` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the project's [`Gemfile.lock`](https://github.com/mhartl/action_cable_chat_app/blob/master/Gemfile.lock#L78) at line 78:

```
jbuilder (2.4.1)
  activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5.1)
  multi_json (~> 1.2)
```

The `2.4.1` version of the [`jbuilder`](https://rubygems.org/gems/jbuilder/versions/2.4.1) gem is depending on an `activesupport` (which is part of Rails) version `< 5.1`. You would need to update at least to [`jbuilder:2.6.3`](https://rubygems.org/gems/jbuilder/versions/2.6.3) to allow updating Rails to `5.1`. [`jbuilder:2.6.4`](https://rubygems.org/gems/jbuilder/versions/2.6.4) finally relaxes the dependency to just `activesupport >= 3.0.0` which would even allow current Rails 6.0beta versions.

**Added by barlop**

answerer mentions in comment, see https://rubygems.org/gems/rails  for dependencies of a gem

(and it includes versions, so, what versions of rails are dependent on what version of dependent gem)

Comment: thanks, I see it seems maybe activesupport may have the same or similar version numbering to rails. Is there a list of all gems that are part of rails? (that's help me to have determined this myself)

Comment: Yes, you can always see the list of dependencies of a gem on its [Rubygems](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails) page.